# Custom iphone keyboard

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I want to make a custom keyboard for my app and want to use the send button to set a character.

If I name all my buttons e.g. *a, *b, *c, *d etc. will it work to have one IBAction which takes the sender, grabs the name e.g. *a > a ? If so, how is this done.

Also, can a button be named as follows *0, *1, *2 rather than *zero, *one, *two?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, variables don't really work that way.  You are confusing the object itself with the name of the variable that points to it.  When your IBaction is passed the UIButton object, it's not passing a variable name along with it, your method defines the variable that references it as `sender`.  And no, variable names cannot start with a digit in Objective C.

A common approach to differentiating between buttons in this way is to set the tag and branch on that.  Alternatively, you can access the title - it depends on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: middaparka's answer mentions [sender currentTitle]. So title should be *zero instead. thanks.

Comment: @alJaree, by the way you are prefixing things with asterisks, it seems like you are talking about variable names.  Is this the case?  If so, `[sender currentTitle]` will not give you the variable name.  It will give you the text on the button.

Comment: Yes. I create a button UIButton *a  and want to get that 'a' and the names of all the other keys that are pressed by using one IBAction and accessing the sender. Is this possible?

Comment: No.  `a` is simply a name for the memory location where the UIButton is stored.  That memory location can have many names.  When it is passed to your IBAction, it has the name `sender`.  There is no way to find out what other names it has.  As I mentioned before, you could use tags, or the button's title, or you may want to store your buttons in a dictionary and access them by key.

Comment: Ok. so there is no way to know the pointers name. I will have to use tags. So just, 1 IBAction and take the sender.tag. The tags are always string type right?

Comment: Tags are always integers, titles are always `NSString *`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to point multiple UIButtons at the same IBAction and then extract the textual label of the button, you can simply use the currentTitle property of the sender.

For example:

```
- (IBAction)padButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed: %@", [sender currentTitle]);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and the naming? can a button be named *0

Comment: @alJaree It's just a textual label, so I don't see why not.

Comment: Will there need to be some kind of type checking on the current title or is it all in String format?

Comment: @alJaree The currentTitle UIButton method returns an NSString pointer. (In essence, the sender *is* the UIButton that was pressed.)

Comment: Apparently they cannot be named using e.g. *0, *1. This is pointed out in Jim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using tags for your buttons.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Button pressed: %i", sender.tag);    

    switch (sender.tag) {

        case 0:
            /*  Button A Pressed  */
            break;
        case 1:
            /*  Button B Pressed  */
            break;

        /*  and so forth...  */
    }   
}
```

You will need to set the tags either in Interface Builder, or programmatically.

Comment: It sure will, seeing as there are a ton of keys on a keyboard to replicate. It's similar to middaparka's answer, only easier to handle.

Comment: Thats why I am going to extract the button title. thanks though :)

Comment: Love to know how this is "easier to handle". :-)